# how do it recover a corrupt git repository

Tags: git

I had an unexpected shutdown last night and now my .git repository is in trouble.
I run `git fsck` and this is my output.

I'm wondering if I can just delete the offending branch from C:\dev\TAS-NIAPS.git\refs\heads?

```
error: refs/heads/my-branch: invalid sha1 pointer 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
error: invalid HEAD
error: bad ref for .git/logs/HEAD
error: bad ref for .git/logs/refs/heads/my-branch
dangling blob 93067c17d6f7cde81d88b6dde4f8c684dc790d58
dangling blob 1d1db408c7a58131bb181bbd8349592eaaec65e8
dangling blob f62ae04e1705383781d3af5c5ee3b2504841ad0f
dangling commit e72c743883e460ab2292fc08dba592838b5c2ca2
dangling blob ce37ecd6a14ec15d8577482c9bc8dd68171ce7b4
dangling blob 9b3c6063c7a08b019d922f99f7aeef3b65074f18
dangling blob 4f3e5c4c1f21727cb8a6d7c30d458328aa869e56
dangling blob 0040bc4828ab92f9b0e1852b0ae099ca2780d192
dangling blob ad42e01f8eb814318f08f6a2042718a1c18ac9a3
dangling blob 415180d7c2a4abd3a3143b5ca6375b0af4022e40
dangling blob d376e4a3ee500f3f3e858ce697584554a44f9bab
dangling blob 8e77f0d4f2a8de979781cf8a755f028874b4c4cf
dangling commit b69dc4ef09b6f3c2dcbd328e897d2337ba0e82ee
dangling blob 13a1d8fd303b7185e7b07945d23dcd0acc243cde
dangling commit 73a524524478bd76a1a9b2471aa6e646abbb4305
dangling blob 7da65419ba862bb24aa3ef0df4aacede4aec55bc
dangling blob acb92863ea624d2c45342410c34a0ffa119001c0
dangling commit 9dc09067fc277964b3c3e42fa024970b6928bcc1
dangling blob 38e3b884c90bc3d5ce68e57955faa2834ecafdaf
dangling commit 96e7142141a67dbba21fd99420cc0d719b3d1cae
dangling blob 0bf0cc07b2079d730e48f4a6e3e9880d1a9a43d7
dangling blob c3f6ecfb6e07e0a05d7a564991eefbbe6f05a0e4
dangling blob 4d0315d2727bf60c39a415b4df6023479130430d
dangling blob 85276deee6a55ebad29a27905690573d2c237820
dangling commit 9b2c59d667d4558e0e8110fe79edd9de48cd7ab0
dangling blob dc30bdd63bda73c376d8897f793cc5d9a7c6a0c3
dangling commit a9323d930cb5a310341a24c30b2e37e5fb1fcc42
dangling blob 7543b95da8317078f606c9940fcf715ae3d9a375
dangling blob 43467568407dafd1e2a0a02e59a36cf86bfb22c2
dangling blob 67647d131199e9b5c7d1221518bfd64d4eef5c8d
dangling commit 3566dd8ef71c5894e49cd3d85143723c4ab68f15
dangling blob 5d73a55b67e44517f40e6a31d2b2d44b8332522e
dangling commit 76a3899ac23ea767b266e2a8271ec85945c376e7
dangling commit a8b195f95abe3ac1797efec8e1a93f33788e3de3
dangling blob a0c175a342ebbb8a2a50354c3ce92e06fa7379e2
dangling commit 94c55da0e14f684aa1fa0b94f0e65312b8686fc1
dangling blob b3d44dbc1b1a4875f108bde2f23a01d60195d3ec
dangling blob 9ddae565bd51fb63eb62fab4274420289a714812
dangling blob 93f9d15f5c6391f41caec4bc7e73adcb343d54ec
dangling blob 52fb7d648db1b28f9abcdfa9da59db391d684406
dangling blob 650ace3ba6a3bf5fe83e8f264be509cb0b2e6b47
dangling blob 562d6690f8df8214fad3dfccbfaca4ca47f8a640
dangling blob 602dc69f8e18a6ed6be2d37b36e072a379c8c491
dangling blob 4537fef53db35c42e5033d0e6645a213f5b35607
dangling blob b3425a7c445107861c2d2e4900994958ff8d019a
dangling blob 29448a81f9f9e6394d85dfeb76ea291cb1abbad3
dangling blob ed44da0e5ad38845ce0812572f0a5fa0ae4ecd76
dangling commit b76ab2ffac69f747639120dc3c277559c12605aa
dangling blob 9e6dbe200ce524e191ee9f6f178d535ce437eb20
dangling blob 0977aea698af5948ad7de9b33f8f44e4bad3941d
dangling commit c683f61d9081c551b5a6275addf681c210b9e1ba
dangling blob 858932468bd46c3d805304eeccb3e00f12b40538
dangling blob 2f9d526b21bee121676cebd637e53814b1b54cdd
dangling blob 63a5f61c62589d034325ee4bcb32a9cdd4779f95
dangling commit 26bfa21ae73c330b92f61acf9f99c4404244b291
dangling blob abc66213cb9659d1cf4093f42d4938f8e7d4caf4
dangling blob b9d152bfdb65cdcf639917604446cb519f47981a
dangling blob 0fd64a0a28b5c23cc6e06b58bd8dabff5f4218ff
dangling blob cde16673c074cd4755cfbf189384808d1b3a09b5
dangling blob 77e99662e9edd5d59d1271dd9ff8adeae9bb7463
dangling blob 57f59ee5e61c6c9b3e804e615e736ebfff1a7376
dangling blob f8f82adeddb80d3cb0e31e02b93879fcae963101
dangling commit 6cff1644bb105019c1888393726bc3416d3e90dc
dangling blob 7501eb437bd2eeb0be27c9674092ca0343beaf35
dangling blob f305e3fffa9ee2e777debc0a8e1369a8ce5ce3c0
dangling blob 420f83e8d5c7dfb39062977280752b095f4d21ba
dangling blob 6912b7a5e3974f3fc51e36be84313242c217bace
dangling blob 6c163ffc8861e0f0aeb986c394a59c495e2c2ecf
dangling blob 8329c76f54066a8e432f112454dbee1e04259e7b
dangling blob 873c4b6bab2f124e8bde3522a192c3664703f8d1
dangling commit 587be36c6e886557664e107a93f503056ea6dd04
dangling blob f38c6f6520d979299e2bcc0ef5aaf6b2e5a71d3c
dangling commit 25910b5d28bfe0c00ebd9e05a84fb3cd78d1b432
dangling commit 7193e3c3ea434a1e509bd99000ced4487aec6c5e
dangling blob 2a9ffbbc388a60f1efcd102e5d01e734e987055c
dangling blob 2fa1c32667c825eebc61fb29bfee5e0f576f2600
dangling blob 0aaf0b3939ebd164b0363b178dd201290d901a19
dangling commit 8bba6f9eaecc4b460d5c7b57ffa71aa04f56a108
dangling blob 87bd9fa4753f20d6a72e11758839cdaf8f14e1f1
dangling blob 03c147ed2b9c8472cf2bc7f3da6340d2c7ca1c74
dangling commit 17d273b54a2a790bedd4ba4d0e5ee548887cef73
dangling blob 2ada7bd72ed3ef409e3460c712310b168c318026
dangling blob f6de97eaad7384d902abf892a7b91d1de340d7f5
dangling commit 29f7275ed8f8151ddd9fd608e641f67402a5f806
dangling blob a2fb6331e500a3f7049b39a6aa94864dbd26d762
```

This `mybranch` isn't important to me, but I would prefer not to have to clone the repository from azure devops again as I would lose my local stashes etc.

Can anything be done here?

Comment: First thing to do: make a copy of the entire directory, including the worktree (if it is not bare) and all connected worktrees. Then you can test whether removal of the offending ref helps. My guess is: it helps.

Comment: thanks, it didn't help much. led to another error. i think i'll just accept i'll lose my stashes here and re-clone. glad for devops and frequent pushes!

Comment: Since the stashes are not mentioned in the fsck output, it should be possible to salvage them into your new clone: copy `.git/logs/refs/stash` to the new repo (only if you do not have the file there already!), and then run `git fsck` in the new clone and copy also any objects that it complains that are missing.

Answer (score 0):

as @j6t suggested in his comment : copy the repo before editing anything by hand.

---

About `HEAD` and `my-branch` : look at `cat .git/HEAD` and `cat .git/refs/heads/my-branch`, and see if they print valid values. If you don't care about `my-branch`, you can delete it as you suggested and recreate it at a past value (do you have a version of `origin/my-branch` ?)

About the log files : the worse part here would be to loose the reflog, but that wouldn't impact the branches.

A log file is a text file which you can open in any text editor, and once you understand its format, you can easily view it and even edit it.

---

Open the mentioned files `.git/logs/HEAD` and `.git/logs/refs/heads/my-branch`, and check wether there is an obvious format issue :

are they obviously truncated at the end ? do you see unexpected characters (binary gibberish, or sequences of `\0`s) at some locations ?

1. If you see a formatting issue : you may "fix" this by deleting the offending sections and saving the file. Run fsck again to see if you have further issues.

The only data you loose is in your reflog :

- things like the "undo stack" effect are altered,
- `git`'s garbage collection may collect commits which previously would have been kept longer.

2. If you don't see formatting issues : this means that some of the commit `<sha>`s mentioned in those reflogs are not valid anymore.

This could mean some corruption in the objects storage ; but given that `git fsck` hasn't mentioned any problem in your existing *commits*, I doubt you will fall in this case.

---

You may actually delete these two specific files entirely -- you will "only" loose the reflog for `HEAD` and `my-branch`.

I'm so used to having the reflog as a safety net that I would look if I could salvage even parts of it before doing so, though.

Comment: updated, I initially skipped the two first lines of your `git fsck` output

Comment: thanks for this - very useful, learnt a lot today!